# Dotnet build fails with `Only one project can be specified` when PublishProfile specified

Tags: .net, jenkins, asp.net-core, .net-core, publish-profiles

I'm playing with CI and trying to build `asp.net core` app and publish it to azure using preconfigured publishing profile. I can run the following command using a command line but when I'm running it with Jenkins (Windows) it fails:

> dotnet build -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=mycoolprofile

And I'm getting the following output with error:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version
15.6.84.34536 for .NET Core Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. Switch: p:PublishProfile=mycoolprofile
```

And of course, I saw all `quotes` discussions, I renamed my profile to be a simple single word, this is the real profile name above.

I'm following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles

Comment: check that Build Agent has correct working folder

Answer (score 7):

Just 'solved' this problem by adding an extra slash.  It seems that `dotnet` swallows it

```
dotnet build //t:MyTarget MyProject.csproj
```

Comment: Make sure if the target / output directories have spaces in them that you quote it ie "C:\frank\and beans\are\for\dinner\".